# Create a custom view using canvas and path in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-canvas

I want to create my custom view. View that has slight sine curve from below and top has just simple other view with whatever color I want to choose. Like I want to also choose gradient color for that view.

**What I tried**

I've tried one SineView and other WaveView in my code but it won't work as expected.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int width = canvas.getWidth();
    int height = canvas.getHeight();
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(0, getMeasuredHeight() / 2F);
    canvas.clipRect(0, -100, 450, 100, Region.Op.INTERSECT);
    Path mPath = new Path();
    mPath.moveTo(0, 100);
    mPath.quadTo(50, -50, 100, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(150, 50, 200, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(250, -50, 300, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(350, 50, 400, 0);
    mPath.quadTo(450, -50, 500, 100);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

**Expected view**

[image: Expected view]

Also I want the view's height can be increase as wrap content. I don't want to increase the sine curve just want to increase layout's height.

Comment: can you share the screenshot of what you tried

Comment: post the whole code of your `SineView`

Comment: ok you posted expected view, but what is the one you got with your code? what is the problem actually? the wrong `Path`?

Comment: Thank you @pskink for answering. I don't know what was the problem. I'm just learning canvas and wants to implement this type of view that remains same from bottom and expand as height increase.

Comment: Thank you guys for commenting. Now I got the solution.